# Relacionamento belongsTo

Tags: cakephp

Gostaria de saber se é possível fazer este tipo de relacionamento na Model do cakephp, se é possível, me mostrem como, pois não estou conseguindo.

Maneira que eu preciso:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
         Status => array(
            'className' => 'Status',
            'foreignKey' => 'status_id_origem', 'status_id_destino',
            'dependent' => false,
         ),
    );
```

Maneira normal:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
         Status => array(
            'className' => 'Status',
            'foreignKey' => 'status_id_origem',
            'dependent' => false,
         ),
    );
```

Especificando melhor o que eu preciso:

executo a seguinte query:

```
    SELECT Historico.*, Status.descricao
       FROM historicos as Historico
             LEFT JOIN statuses as Status
                     ON (Status.id = Historico.status_id_origem)
```

Logo essa query me retorna o seguinte:

```
     id integer|status_id_origem integer|status_id_destino integer|descricao
     ----------|------------------------|-------------------------|---------
          44   |        1               | 2                       | Aguardando embarque
          43   |        1               | 2                       | Aguardando embarque
```

Mas o que eu realmente preciso que ela me retorne é o seguinte:

```
     id integer|status_id_origem integer|status_id_destino integer|descricaoIdOrigem varchar|descricaoIdDestino varchar
     ----------|------------------------|-------------------------|-------------------------|------------------------
          44   |        1               | 2                       | Aguardando embarque     |    Embarcado
          43   |        1               | 2                       | Aguardando embarque     |    Embarcado
```

Comment: As duas maneiras postadas são idênticas, qual é o problema? (tem um erro também)

Comment: Opa, desculpa @VirgilioNovic, falha minha, saí na correria aqui e acabei colocando duas vezes o mesmo código, é que na maneira que eu preciso eu coloco duas referências na ForeignKey e na maneira normal, deve-se colocar apenas uma, poderia me ajudar nesta questão?

Comment: (Já editei a pergunta)

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações, pois costumamos mantê-las o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Comment: Ok @diegofm, muito obrigado! 
xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido da seguinte maneira:

Realmente permaneceu da mesma forma:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
         Status => array(
            'className' => 'Status',
            'foreignKey' => 'status_id_origem',
            'dependent' => false,
         ),
    );
```

Maneira que eu estava fazendo:

```
    SELECT Historico.*, Status.descricao
       FROM historicos as Historico
             LEFT JOIN statuses as Status
                     ON (Status.id = Historico.status_id_origem)
```

Logo essa query me retorna o seguinte:

```
     id integer|status_id_origem integer|status_id_destino integer|descricao
     ----------|------------------------|-------------------------|---------
          44   |        1               | 2                       | Aguardando embarque
          43   |        1               | 2                       | Aguardando embarque
```

Maneira que achei o que eu precisava:

```
    SELECT Historico.*, Status.descricao, Statuse.descricao
       FROM historicos as Historico
             LEFT JOIN statuses as Status
                     ON (Status.id = Historico.status_id_origem)
             LEFT JOIN statuses as Statuse
                     ON (Statuse.id = Historico.status_id_destino):
```

Logo essa query me retorna o seguinte:

```
     id integer|status_id_origem integer|status_id_destino integer|  descricao  varchar  |  descricao  varchar
     ----------|------------------------|-------------------------|----------------------|---------------------
          44   |        1               |          2              | Aguardando embarque  |    Embarcado
          43   |        1               |          2              | Aguardando embarque  |    Embarcado
```